# cannot connect to sql server from management studio

Tags: sql-server

Hi I am not experienced in sql server admin. I have in program files microsoft sql server
and the properties say it is 225 mb and contains 499 files ....version not mentioned : I do not know if it 05/08 /12 .....and I did not install it ; perhaps gotten installed with visual studio 2013 trial copy ; or with visual studio 13 for web which I have installed recently.
anyway now I have installed sql server management studio express and wanted to connect to sql server.
I tried   as instance name  mycomputer name which is kobosh  and the default instance name   : kobosh/mssqlserver but I cannot connect

### TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to kobosh\MSSQLSERVER.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is not valid) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 87)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=87&LinkId=20476

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Answer (score 1):

Try kobosh\SQLEXPRESS assuming the SQL Server has been installed on kobosh.

Comment: thanks not work either. I looked into sql.server.exe and tried to run it and I have error saying either file is corrupt or been tampered with uninstall it and try again. so looked into control panel and uninstalled one of the sql files then came back to run sqlserver.exe again and boom it was not there

Comment: Do you have **Sql Server Configuration Manager** in Start menu?

Comment: My suggestion is to start with a clean machine and reinstall SQL Server and Management Studio (EXPRESS edition). Leave the defaults and then when you connect try kobosh\SQLEXPRESS.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is started.  If not, start it.  Then, use localhost as the name of the server to connect to.

Comment: I do not see it listed in local services

Comment: Then it probably isn't installed